# keras classifier.fit() method showing shape error?

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

```
classifier = Sequential()
classifier.add(Dense(6,kernel_initializer='random_uniform',activation='relu',input_dim=11))
classifier.add(Dense(6,kernel_initializer='random_uniform',activation='relu'))
classifier.add(Dense(1,activation='sigmoid'))
classifier.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='binary_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
classifier.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size = 10, epochs = 100)
```

> ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_4_input to have shape (11,) but got array with shape (16934,)

Comment: You told Keras to expect 11 dimensions, but the data has 16934 dimensions. You need to tell Keras the truth about your data.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't gave us information on x_train shape but I guess that your `x_train` shape is `(x, 16934)`, using the batch_size you're giving `(10, 16934)` while the input Dense layer is looking for data shaped as `(10, 11)` where x represent the number of samples in your x_train.

Comment: yes my x_train shape is (7500, 16934) what can i do to make that work?

Comment: Just change `classifier.add(Dense(6,kernel_initializer='random_uniform',activation='relu',input_dim=11))` to `classifier.add(Dense(6,kernel_initializer='random_uniform',activation='relu',input_dim=16936))`